# Autorun USB Windows 7

Tags: windows, usb, autorun

I would like to create a USB stick with a simple HTML file in it which opens when the stick gets plugged in. It is meant to be some kind of merchandise thing. Thing is that I read that Microsoft disabled Autorun on Windows 7 for security reasons. But despite that I have such a USB stick lying around which does the exactly the thing I'm looking for. Unfortunately it is not displayed as a removable drive, therefore I can not take a look into it.

Can anyone recommend a method, which works on as many devices (with different OS, different Settings) as possible?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are searching for the `autorun.inf` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki.Autorun.inf

you can write  your own *autorun.inf* and copy it on the stick (if it does not show up as removable disk format it, maybe run a data rescue tool first) if this will work depends on the os settings of the specific computer you plug in the stick. if autorun is disabled in the os it will not work...